# Replace multiple selects with the same set of options

Tags: javascript

I am building a dynamic page where if the user changes a select the nested forms get updated.  These nested forms can contain multiple selects.  I need to replace all the options (and only the options) and keep the selects as they have unique id's etc.

I did this before with a single select (`dropdown`) which was easy like this:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = data[i].id;
      option.text = data[i].related_select_label;
      dropdown.add(option);
    }
```

I am doing a JSON request here and the for loop adds all the new options.  In my new case I want to build the new list then insert these into all the target selects on my page.  That's easy - I am stumped on how to build this list of selects.

I tried this:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = data[i].id;
      option.text = data[i].related_select_label;
      options << option.text
    }
```

which I would follow with a second loop to replace the selects contents with the options:

```
item.innerHTML = options
```

This doesn't work (options is undefined).

My JS is not very strong so I suspect I am just missing something obvious and am open to a different solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - I just built a full select then pulled the innerHTML:

```
    let select = document.createElement('select');
    let defaultOption = document.createElement('option');
    defaultOption.text = 'Select a budget item...';
    defaultOption.value = '';
    select.add(defaultOption);
    select.selectedIndex = 0;
    let option;
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = data[i].id;
      option.text = data[i].select_label;
      select.add(option)
    }

    this.budgetItemSelectTargets.forEach(
      (item) => {
        item.innerHTML = select.innerHTML
    })
```

Comment: I think this solution relies on some unseen details of your `this` object -- which is great: if it works, it works! Note that a more general solution might also be possible by using `select.cloneNode(true)`. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode if you're interested.)